# Change network binding of Azure Function running in VS 2017 development environment

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

As part of an up coming project I am investigating various Azure functionality. I am current looking at collecting data from remote sensors using Azure Functions.

I have a test function, running through VS 2017, written in c# and is fired using a HTTPTrigger. When launched it starts a dotnet console program and binds to 127.0.0.1.

I have a second project written using Python that reads a text file and performs a HTTP POST request to the Azure function for each line of the text file. The Azure function fires for each line and does some dummy processing and stores the results in a database.

The Python program is simulating a hardware device (might be custom hardware, might be a PC) that will ultimately collect some arbitrary data and send them back via these HTTP requests.

I cannot work out how to change the Azure function to bind to an external NIC address (i.e. 192.168.0.34) rather than 127.0.0.1 so that we can test this across the network from one of these external devices.

I understand that this will ultimately run in the Azure Cloud environment but at this point we just want to conduct some basic tests locally.

Can the Azure function, running through VS 2017 on a Windows 10 PC, be bound to listen on a different address (not port number)?

Comment: The question is too general. Where is your hardware emitting data to so that your Function can be triggered by a new data payload? What trigger type are you using for your Function?

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me. @Goose wants to know how to get the function to listen on a different network interface address, because by default it listens on 127.0.0.1. I'm facing the same problem and really can't see someone down voted this question.

Comment: I have edited the question since that previous comment to make it clearer. However, I never did find an answer and have had to test online in Azure. It's not ideal as it is slower progress than testing code locally.